# NoMethodError after replicating RCV pattern in 2 other objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have replicated the same pattern a 3rd time in my rails app, and suddenly the page loads but the form will not submit. The issue looks like:

```
NoMethodError in Transportation#new
Showing /home/cchilders/projects/rails_projects/jared_test/app/views/transportation/new.html.erb where line #12 raised:

undefined method `transportations_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc3e8013a20>:0x007fc3ee3c0fc8>
Extracted source (around line #12):
10
11
12
13
14
15

<div>
  <div>
    <%= form_for(@transportation) do |f| %>
        <div>
          <%= f.label :name %><br>
          <%= f.text_area :name %>

Rails.root: /home/cchilders/projects/rails_projects/jared_test
```

in transportation_controller we have:

```
class TransportationController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @transportations = Transportation.all
    end

    def new
        @transportation = Transportation.new
    end

    def create
        @transportation = Transportation.new(transportation_params)
        if @transportation.save
            redirect_to '/vacations'
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private 
      def transportation_params
          params.require(:transportation).permit(:name)
      end

end
```

in routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    get '/vacations'     => 'vacations#index'
    get 'vacations/new'  => 'vacations#new'
    post '/vacations'    => 'vacations#create'

    get '/destinations'     => 'destinations#index'
    get 'destinations/new'  => 'destinations#new'
    post '/destinations'    => 'destinations#create'

    get '/transportation'         => 'transportation#index'
    get 'transportation/new'      => 'transportation#new'
    post '/transportation'        => 'transportation#create'
```

What's so weird is I checked the pattern vs destinations and vacations, and the pattern is the same for each. The only difference I can imagine is the models, but all I'm trying to do is make an object with one field...the other 2 models are much more complicated and save correctly

The issue is on form submission only, the page loads. The page is as follows:

```
<%= render :template => 'base' %> 


<div>
  <div>
    <h1>Add transportation</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <%= form_for(@transportation) do |f| %>
        <div>
          <%= f.label :name %><br>
          <%= f.text_area :name %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= f.submit "Create" %>
        </div>
    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

My transportation schema is so simple:

```
 create_table "transportations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

This form was demanding a URL of '/transportations', not transportation. Can someone explain in detail how the naming works in Rails? I am getting puzzle by naming the model Vacation, the SQL comes up as `create table vacations`, making a single object should be named singularly, but the URL expects plural. What is the proper pattern to craft a basic rails app with CRUDing a single model?

Also, what do you do about mouse vs mice or sheep vs sheep? Use `sheeps`? Thank you

Comment: Not sure if it is just a typo in your post, but you have `get '/transportation'         => 'transportation#index'` and should have `get '/transportations'         => 'transportations#index'`.  That would explain your error.

Comment: yes sir, but why? why must it be transportations? In the `create` view I named it `@transportation = Transportation.new` which is singular

Comment: also a publicly facing URL of `transportations`, `mouses`, and/or `shrimps` seems ridiculous and dangerously unprofessional. How do you railsers handle this?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're joking or not, but rails works by conventions and logic, not magic. You sir, are expecting magic here from a piece of software.

Comment: @codyc4321 look into REST

Comment: Rails handles most irregular plurals correctly (e.g. words like mouse/mice), but if you want to override how Rails is "pluralizing", you can do it in `/config/initializers/inflections.rb`.

Comment: I'm similarly not sure if you're joking or not, but wondering how the MVC handles irregular plurals must not be expecting magic, since it handles them automatically, according to the other more polite people posting

Comment: I guess `/config/initializers/inflections.rb` is more of a permanent thing, but you can still override one word for a specific table like the answer says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add additional input on the naming conventions. This is why when you generate `rails generate model vacation` you will get in your database `vacations` table. Rails utilizes approach of Convention over configuration

> By default, Active Record uses some naming conventions to find out how the mapping between models and database tables should be created. Rails will pluralize your class names to find the respective database table. So, for a class Book, you should have a database table called books.

There are also ways to override this convention and in case you have a different name of the table let's say `my_vacantions` in database you can bind the model to it following way

```
class Vacation < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "my_vacations"
end
```

And for the final part of your question,  guess what ruby knows how to convert that type of things properly, therefore here is the answer for you :) sheep will be sheep and mouse will be mice

```
'sheep'.pluralize            # => "sheep"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use rails resources for routes.  If you want to limit them you can

```
resources :transportations, only: [:new, :create, :index]
```

When using `form_for(@transportation)` rails guesses at the correct place to route to based on the object.  So you can either use resources or set the url explicitly

`form_for(@transportation, url: "/transportation")`